# set timestamp to bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: php, laravel-5, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm working with Laravel 5, in a view I'm using the *bootstrap datetimepicker* I have a timestamp saved in the database, and when the user load that view I want to preload that date in the *datetimepicker*. As I read there's a method  `datepicker('setDate',startDate);` to set the date, but I need to assign the value that is accesible trought PHP, as I am using blade my timestamp is accesible with:

```
{{$contract->myTimestamp}}
```

So, I can I do it?

HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-sm-10" style="height:10px;">
      <div class="form-group">
             <div class='input-group date' data-date-startdate="{{$contract->myTimestamp}}" name="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" id='datetimepicker{{$contract->id}}' >
             <input type='text' class="form-control" id="fecha">
                 <span class="input-group-addon">
                       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                       </span>
                 </span>
              </div>                                                        
           </div>
```

in the JS I added:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(this).datetimepicker().datetimepicker('setDate',startDate);
    });
```

Now It shows me the date, but doesn't let me edit it, I mean when I click on the button to chage the date  nothing happens,So I whas thinking that it could be a trouble with the format of the date, because in the database I have something like *2015-11-28 20:10:14* and in the datetimepicker I have *12/03/2015 12:00 AM* and they are differents formats. So how can I transform the date?thanks!

Comment: Please add more code, where is the HTML/blade part of your code?

Comment: Also please add your current datetimepicker code.

Comment: I edited the post man @AndyNoelker

Comment: @MinaYoussef post edited!

Comment: First of all, you are not calling datetimepicker on your div - you are calling it on `$(this)` which references `$(document)`. So change your datetimepicker function to reference the id of the div. I am not sure what `{{$contract->id}}` becomes, but presuming it is something like `_23`, then change your javascript to be `$('#datetimepicker_23').datetimepicker({defaultDate: startDate});`. If your javascript is in the blade file, you can use the blade syntax in the selector for dynamic ids. Change that and let me know what you get.

Comment: thanks man! I didnt know that I could use blade syntax in the selector

Comment: To be clear, you can only include blade syntax in your javascript **if you are including that javascript within your blade file**. If you have an external javascript file, you cannot use blade templating. If that works, please let me know and I can make it an answer so that others can see.